# Django - How to check multiple variables in the view or in the template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have a site that the user selects a drop-down menu item, inputs some JSON, and then clicks "Parse". Then the JSON data is checked against certain properties based on the drop-down menu item. Basically I have a list that looks like this.

```
myList = [{'Prop1': ['asdf', 'wefef']}, {'prop3': ['ss']}, {'prop2': ['d']}]
```

This is all the data I am checking against. It is the property name and then a list of expected values for that property name. Then in the JSON I have to compare those properties against the JSON properties in the list above.

Right now I am not sure where the best way to go about checking these. Should I do it in my `views.py` or should I do it in the `page.html`?

Basically I will need to look through `myList` and check if that property is in the JSON. If so then I need to check it against the expected property. And then I need to print things in a row so that you can view the info like:

```
Property   Excepted Value   Actual Value    P/F
prop1      asdf, wefef      apple           F
prop2      d                d               P
prop3      ss               sd              F
```

My issue is, this will be a bunch of logic to build out to parse correctly. I am new to Django and not sure if the amount of code should be done in the HTML file. Else, I would need to build a large string in the views.py that contains all the data and the HTML, then pass to the HTML file and just display a single variable that displays all the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practise not to put too much logic in your page.html - it should just display your data. Therefore, put the logic into your view. 
It also has the advantage that you can test the functionality way easier.